# html Checkbox in laravel send true on every request

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel send true in every request with different html tags:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('is_english',null,null, array('id'=>'whatever')) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('is_english',null, array('id'=>'whatever')) }}
```

And it send "on"; i want to send 1 or 0 
What can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::checkbox('is_english',1,null, array('id'=>'whatever')) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('is_english',0,null, array('id'=>'whatever')) }}
```

First argument : name

Second argument : value

Third argument : checked or not checked this takes: true or false

Fourth argument : additional attributes (e.g., checkbox css classes)

for detail you can read

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/167/creating-a-checkbox-input-field